# "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm new to Node/React, and I'm creating a learning project. It's platform that connects freelancers with nonprofit companies. Users (freelancers) view a list of companies, and click a button to connect to a company. Once this is clicked, the user will have that company added as a relationship in the database. This is working correctly.

Now I'm trying to have a page where the user can view all their connections (the companies they connected with). The solution below works but only if the user has at least one connection. Otherwise, I get the error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

To figure out which JSX to render, I'm using a conditional to see if the user has connections. If not, I wanna show "You have no connections". I'm doing this by checking `if (!companies.length)` then show "you have no connections". `companies` is set as in empty array in the state. I don't understand why it's undefined. Even if the user has no connections, `companies` is still an empty array. so why why would `companies.length` return this error? How can I improve this code to avoid this problem?

```
function UserConnections() {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const connections = currentUser.connections;
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
    Promise.all(comps).then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));
  }, [connections]);

  if (!companies.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You have no connections</p>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {companies.map(c => (
          <CompanyCard
            key={c.companyHandle}
            companyHandle={c.companyHandle}
            companyName={c.companyName}
            country={c.country}
            numEmployees={c.numEmployees}
            shortDescription={c.shortDescription}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Edit: Sorry, I should've included that the error is being thrown from a different component (UserLoginForm). This error is thrown when the user who has no connections logs in. But in the UserConnections component (code above), if I change `if (!companies.length)` to `if (!companies)`, the user can login fine, but UserConnections will not render anything at all. That's why I was sure the error is refering to the `companies.length` in the UserConnections component.

The UserLoginForm component has been working fine whether the user has connections or not, so I don't think the error is coming from here.

**UserLoginForm**

```
function UserLoginForm({ loginUser }) {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory();

  // Handle form submission 
  async function handleSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let results = await loginUser(formData);
    if (results.success) {
      history.push("/companies");
    } else {
      setFormErrors(results.errors);
    }
  }

  // Handle change function 
  function handleChange(evt) {
    const { name, value } = evt.target;
    setFormData(d => ({ ...d, [name]: value }));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>User Login Form</h1>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div>
              <input
                name="username"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Username"
                value={formData.username}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                name="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                value={formData.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </div>

            {formErrors.length
              ? <Alert type="danger" message={formErrors} />
              : null
            }

            <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary my-3">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
};
```

Edit 2: The solutions provided in this thread actually solved the problem. The error message kept persisting due to a different problem coming from another component.

Comment: `undefined` is not the same as an empty array.

Comment: `Promise.all` will always return an array, so it should be impossible to have `companies` be undefined, is this all your code?  You could of course do an undefined check, but I'd be interested to know how your getting undefined in the first place.  You do have some extra brackets, `then((comps => setCompanies(comps)));` but I don't think that would be doing it, could you try `then(comps => setCompanies(comps));` and see if that makes a difference..

Comment: I believe there is something fishy going on here, the answers you have been given on doing an undefined check, is not solving your main problem.  Looking at your code provided I cannot see how your getting `undefined`, (no paths would do that).  But I might have an idea what might be your issue, in React if you use any hooks conditionally it will mess up the state's of other components, it's the reason there are linting rules to prevent this.  So I've a feeling your problem might not be this one, but another component that has messed up React hooks stack.  Just a though!!

Comment: @Keith You're right that something is going on. I tried to keep my question short and concise, so I can get answers. This error happens when the user that has no connections logs in, not when you go to UserConnections. But I'm positive the problem is in UserConnections. If I do `if (!companies)` instead of `if (!companies.length)`, the user logs in fine and I get no errors. But when you go to UserConnections, nothing is rendered at all. So the problem is in `companies.length` for sure I think.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in other components when a user has no connections?, especially things like `if (currentUser.connections) { useEffect(); useState(); etc.. } else { useEffect(); etc.... }`  This will mess up Reacts internal state in a really bad way.  And because your saying it's only when!!, it seems very possible it's `if` related..

Comment: Another common error `if (something) return;  useEffect(); useState(); //etc`  not easy to spot, but still dangerous to React.

Comment: @Keith I edited the OP to include the code from the UserLoginForm component.  I'm using state in there for form data and form errors. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I can't see any `UserConnections` been used in your `UserLoginForm`,

Comment: @Keith Yeah, that's why I didn't think the problem was there, but it is the component that's throwing the error. The error is pointing me to a line that simply has a div for the password field, which doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: mmm, could you post the error's callstack too,..  I'm just not seeing any issues with the code posted.

Comment: @Keith I'm an idiot. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. The solution provided in this thread actually solved the problem exactly as intended. I was signing on with the wrong password, and for whatever reason, that was triggering `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I have a completely different problem to deal with, but the original problem is solved. Thank you so much for your help @Keith

Comment: No problem, glad you got it solved..   These things are meant to test us..  :)

Comment: "That's why I was sure the error is refering to the companies.length in the UserConnections component." The error message shows the exact file name and line number where the error occurs. There is no need to assume or guess. I just want to point this out to you for future reference. Even when the error rmessage is the same, you should check the file name and line number because you will often make the same mistake in multiple places. (I know I do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

`{companies.map(c => (...)}`

to this:

`{companies && companies.map(c => (...)}`

and this:

`if (!companies.length) {`

to this:

`if (!companies || companies.length === 0) {`

This will then check for a nullish value, before running the map operation or checking length.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem remains. If I log in with a user that has no connections, I get "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: @bourne2077   Are you sure it's this component that's throwing the error?.  Although none of those checks are required, doing them should at least stop an error in this component.  As such, it's surely coming from somewhere else.  Alternatively, is it that the code sent to the browser is different to what your showing, eg. it's not compiled etc..

Comment: @Keith Sorry you're right. I should've put this in the OP. The error is coming from the UserLoginForm component when the the user who has no connections logs in. But if I change `if (!companies.length) to `(!companies)` the user logs in fine with no errors, but UserConnections will not render anything. This lead me to believe the problem is coming from the UserConnections component, from which the code is posted in OP.

Comment: @bourne2077  I wonder if it's worth posting `UserLoginForm` just in case.  Your right in initially keeping your question concise, and not just code dumping, but with this one it might be better posting more code.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Even if the user has no connections, companies is still an empty array. so why why would companies.length return this error?

Your assumption that `companies` is an empty array is incorrect. Somehow it is set to `undefined`. You can either protect against this by doing

```
  if (!companies || companies.length == 0) {
```

or by making sure `companies` is always set to an array.

Comment: `companies` indeed does appear to be undefined, but looking at the OP's code, I'd be interested to know how, seen as initial state is `[]` and `Promise.all()` will always be an array too.   Interesting!!!, I think there is something else going on here..

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I tried this solution, but unfortantely I still get the same error.

Comment: @bourne2077 Are you sure it's the exact same error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"? Or is it something like "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" or something else slightly different and on a different line?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes it's the same exact error, but I figured out what's going on. I edited the original post. Thank you very much for your help.